# Add multiple in memory XmlDocument to a GZipStream or to a zip file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gzipstream

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I have an action method that must return one or more xml. These XML files will be in memory, I will generate each XML for an Entity Framework data model. At the end I will have this var: `List<XmlDocument> docs;`

And not sure if I can return multiple files in an Action method. To return only one, I've thought that I could return a zip with all of them.

Reading the MSDN documentation I see  that I can do this:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument( ); 
MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream( );
xmlDoc.Save( xmlStream );
GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(xmlStream, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
```

But, how can I add more than one file to a `GZipStream`? And, what do I have to do to set a name for each doc in `GZipStream`?

I'm sorry but this is the first time I do this and I'm searching how to do it, but I haven't found how to add multiples `MemoryStream` in a GZipStream.

Comment: gzipstream does not allow for multiple files. You should look into using [dotnetzip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

GZipStream does not support multiple files.
Use [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/) to compress multiple files.